Why is reversing a condition with $not returns different result?
I'm testing this on mongoplayground. Why are these 2 queries return different results?

First query
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
      $gte: 88
  }
})


Second query: reverse the condition with $not
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
    "$not": {
      $lt: 88
    }
  }
})

Normally, when the field is an array, only one element match is enough for array match. However, in this query, it seems that every array element needs to be matched for array match.


My sample dataset:
[
  {
    "key": [
      87,
      88
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": [
      88,
      89
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": [
      86,
      90
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": [
      93,
      89,
      71
    ]
  }
]


Based on my understanding, the $not here will check every element must fulfill the filter criteria. If you want to use $not operator to find with at least 1 element not less than, you need work with $elemMatch. Demo. Besides, from the docs: The operation of the $not operator is consistent with the behavior of other operators but may yield unexpected results with some data types like arrays

lt:88 will give at least one not less than 88. so the negation of it will be all of them greater than or equal to 88

Very similar this other question about elemMatch and the answers provided there explain the behaviour as well. TL;DR: The difference between what you expect and what actually happens is because key is an array. So the < or >= checks return documents which have at least one element meeting the criteria. Applying a $not excludes the whole document which matched the inner criteria.

$not perform a logical NOT. The second query will assess "does key have a value < 88"? If the answer is yes (truthy) it will not be included in matching docs because you have inverted the condition and converted a yes (truthy) it to a no (falsey). This has side effects you need to be aware of which are explained in this answer.

So the point is that $NOT works on the whole expression, not just a single condition. E.g. !(!test(89) || !test(88)) = test(89) && test(88), test here means $gte: 88. Instead of !(!test(89)) || !(!test(88)) = test(89) || test(88)

Condition { key: { $gte: 88 } } would be true for these elements.
{ key: [ 87, *88* ] }       -> true
{ key: [ *88*, *89* ] }     -> true
{ key: [ *86*, *90* ] }     -> true
{ key: [ *93*, *89*, 71 ] } -> true

Thus all documents are returned
Condition { key: { $lt: 88 } } would be true for these elements.
{ key: [ *87*, 88 ]  }     -> true
{ key: [ 88, 89 ] }        -> false
{ key: [ *86*, 90 ] }      -> true
{ key: [ 93, 89, *71* ] }  -> true

Using condition $not: {...} returns only { key: [ 88, 89 ] }
If you have only a single value, then for { key: { $gte: 88 } } it would be
{ key: 87 } -> true
{ key: 88 } -> true
{ key: 89 } -> false

Condition { key: { $lt: 88 } } would be true for these elements.
{ key: 87 } -> false
{ key: 88 } -> false
{ key: 89 } -> true

Thus, $not: {...} returns the same as first query.
Mongo Playground
